# Is there a difference in the story between Convert and Fight

Tags: riddick-franchise, the-chronicles-of-riddick

I have the Chronicles of Riddick on DVD and when the DVD starts i see this

[image]

when i choose convert there is a short animation of Riddick in Necropolis when the Lord Marshal is going to have Riddick's mind read

[image]

choosing fight shows a short animation of the sun rising on Crimatoria, particular the part where Riddick sees it and tells Jack/Kira to *"Get your ass moving!"*, however unlike Convert it shows an original image at the end

[image]

I have used both menus and seen the movie and to me it seems the same however at times i notice small scenes i havn't seen before and this is with any movie i rewatch so i can't really tell if the movie is any different between Convert or Fight.

So i am wondering if there is some sort of difference? if not is there a reason why there's 2 different menus?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The sole difference seems to be the menu. A very quick look at the DVD structure reveals that there's only one video track so there can't possibly be any difference in the actual film from choosing either convert or fight.

Per [CinemaBlend](http://www.cinemablend.com/dvds/The-Chronicles-of-Riddick-Unrated-Director-s-Cut-768.html)

> There is a choice that can be made watching this DVD, you can
>   “convert” or “fight”. To “convert” will lead you to a DVD menu veered
>   more towards the Necromongers, while to “fight” will have more
>   Riddick-like menus, as well as an easter egg with actor Colm Feore on
>   set learning how to take a kick.

Both [DVDActive](http://www.dvdactive.com/easter-eggs/dvd/chronicles-of-riddick-directors-cut-the.html) and [MovieMistakes](http://www.moviemistakes.com/film4288/eastereggs) highlight where to go to access the 'easter egg' scene of the actors complaining about their tight armour

> On the opening menu for the full screen version DVD, you have two
>   options, to either Convert or Fight. The Easter Egg is available on
>   both options. If you chose Convert and after the menu loads press the
>   up arrow, you will highlight a part of the pedestal where Riddick
>   stands in the movie. The scene available is a behind the scenes look
>   between Riddick and the Lord Marshal. The scene is also available if
>   you chose the Fight option; you just have to press the left arrow and
>   highlight one of the knives to watch the same scene.

Comment: Just as an FYI, I can confirm this is the case. I've watched the it enough to know.